# BrowserSolc not defined

Tags: javascript, solc

I'm trying to use BrowserSolc in my dApp, but it's just not loading, it seems. I've got `browser-solc.min.js` in the same folder as `index.html`, with the following near the top of the page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="browser-solc.min.js"></script>
```

- and later:

```
BrowserSolc.getVersions(function(soljsonSources, soljsonReleases) {
  console.log(soljsonSources);
  console.log(soljsonReleases);
});
```

This results in an `Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserSolc is not defined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is a TypeScript compile error, add a file at src/typings.d.ts containing:

```
declare var BrowserSolc: any;
```

That just let's the compiler know that BrowserSolc is a real thing even tho it can't see it (because the TypeScript compiler does not load the scripts in  tags).